# Awk syntax error when trying to substitute a pattern

Tags: awk, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

```
awk '{ 
        if($0 !~ /^#/) 
            print "chr"$0;
        else if(match($0,/(##contig=<ID=)(.*)/,m))
            print m[1]"chr"m[2];
        else print $0 
      }' no_chr.vcf > with_chr.vcf
```

I get the following error:

```
awk: line 4: syntax error at or near ,
awk: line 6: syntax error at or near else
```

Any help will be very appreciated!!

Comment: What version of awk are you using? If it isn't `gawk`, I don't believe the third parameter of the `match()` function is allowed.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could be a GNU-free alternative

```bash
awk '
    ! /^#/          { print "chr" $0; next }
    /##contig=<ID=/ { sub(/<ID=/, "<ID=chr"); print; next }
    1
' no_chr.vcf > with_chr.vcf
```

Answer (score 0):

enhancing upon `@`**`glenn jackmann`**'s solution :

- ```
  mawk '/##contig=<ID=/ < /^#/ || sub(/^#/ ? "<ID=" : "^", "&chr")'
  ```

-- or avoid duplication by saving regex outcome

- ```
  gawk '/##contig=<ID=/ < (_=/^#/) || sub(_? "<ID=" : "^", "&chr")'
  ```